# Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SessionParameter' does not have a public property named 'DbType'

Tags: asp.net, sql, parameters, objectdatasource

I am using a Session Parameter on an ObjectDataSource. It works fine on the local development machine but I get this error after copying the website to the production server:

Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SessionParameter' does not have a public property named 'DbType'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me again!

First Answer I gave was WRONG!
Correct answer is that .NET Framework v3.5 was installed, and it needs to be updated to .NET framework 3.5 SP1

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer but I don't know why it does this.

I just removed the DBType property and it worked fine.

Comment: Just had the same thing happen to me.  Maybe the dev box is loading 3.5 assemblies and the production site is loading 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

I change DbType to Type and this got the site working.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is replace DBType by Type. And find the Ansi especification.

By example I have this code:

```
DBType ="AnsiString"
```

an change it by

```
Type="String"
```

and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Travis' answer gave me a clue, but perhaps it could be stated better thusly:

Somehow, in copying the website to the production server, a number of the parameter objects (Specifically, those with type GUID) had the "Type"="Guid" element changed to "DBType"="Guid".

e.g parameter should be:

NOT

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed:  This requires .NET Framework 3.5 **SP1** update.

Answer (score 0):

Wow I also removed DbType="Date" and it started working. did'nt even bother publishing, just changed it on the server with notepad.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well. you should change it.
eg. 
if it is
DbType="Guid"
then change it to 
Type="Object"