# Type ‘System.Web.UI.WebControls.SessionParameter’ does not have a public property named ‘DbType’

Tags: asp.net

I read this:
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184254/type-systemwebuiwebcontrolssessionparameter-does-not-have-a-public-property-nam)

My dev box , everything runs fine. On production server, they installed V3.5 framework and i got to my site and i got this error.

Do I have to do something to get it to read the V3.5 assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar awhile back, had to do with SP1 on my dev box and vanilla 3.5 on production

Answer (score 1):

Matt, turns out I had the same issue as you. Sp1 on dev box and the vanilla version on production server